# I want to Perform Left Outer Join on BarcodePost

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, asp.net-core

Here I want to Perform Left Outer Join on BarcodePost in LINQ I have used defaultIfEmpty() but it does not return the expected result .

```
var result = (from data in _dbContext.MaterialInwardBarcodes
                            join material in _dbContext.MaterialInwardDetails on data.ProductId equals material.ProductId
                            join prod in _dbContext.Products on data.ProductId equals prod.Id
                            join vendor in _dbContext.Vendors on data.VendorId equals vendor.Id
                            join barcode in _dbContext.BarcodePost on data.Barcode equals barcode.BarcodeNumber into barcodeGroup
                            from barcode in barcodeGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where material.MaterialInwardHeaderId == data.RefId && material.Quantity - barcode.Quantity > 0
                            where data.Date <= date && data.VendorId == vendorId
                            select new VendorWiseStock()
                            {
                                VendorName = vendor.Name,
                                ProductId = prod.Id,
                                CurrentStock = material.Quantity - barcode.Quantity
                            }).ToListAsync();
```

```
join barcode in _dbContext.BarcodePost on data.Barcode equals barcode.BarcodeNumber into barcodeGroup
                            from barcode in barcodeGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

In above code I have used Left Outer Join on barcode using defaultIfEmpty() but still it returns null data instead of providing me the data of other table. Here barcode.Quantity can be null but it provides the whole data as null if barcode.Quantity is not available can someone provide me other way or what should I change in the above code.

Comment: If collection `_dbContext.BarcodePost`  has reference item type (class or record, but not struct), then `barcode` can be null and so `barcode.Quantity` should probably cause `NullReferenceException` (due to `barcodeGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()`). In this case, it should be changed to 'barcode?.Quantity'.